# Sybase ASE data purge batch - waitfor and transaction log management

Tags: batch-processing, sap-ase

I am working on a Sybase ASE (migrating to 15.7) data purge utility to be used by multiple tables/ databases to delete huge amount of unwanted older data. I am planning to schedule it nightly 12:00 to 3:00 AM and after 3:00 AM, it is supposed to sleep and wake up at 12:00 PM next day and continue the purge. The criteria is not to affect the users.

1. Is this a good design to use the following to put the batch to sleep until the next day? or is it going to harm the performance? I am committing the tran before invoking waitfor.

   ```
   waitfor time "12:00:00"
   ```
2. Transaction log:

   - I am finding the transaction log size using the below query and waiting untill the transaction log available space < some%. Is this a good approach?
   - Also, considering my generic scenario, what is the optimal transaction log used %limit that I should check for before going on wait?
     -Should I use "dump transaction"? I read that we shouldn't use "dump transaction truncate only" in production systems. Should I use it in a different way? Do you suggest me something for my scenario?

     ```
     select @tlogPctUsed = ceiling(100 * (1 - 1.0 * lct_admin("logsegment_freepages",d.dbid) / sum(case when u.segmap in (4, 7) then u.size end)))
       from master..sysdatabases d, master..sysusages u
      where u.dbid = d.dbid
        and d.dbid = db_id()
        and d.status != 256
     group by d.dbid

     while (@tlogPctUsed > @tlogPctLimit)
     begin
         waitfor delay @10Seconds
         select @tlogPctUsed = ceiling(100 * (1 - 1.0 * lct_admin("logsegment_freepages",d.dbid) / sum(case when u.segmap in (4, 7) then u.size end)))
           from master..sysdatabases d, master..sysusages u
          where u.dbid = d.dbid
            and d.dbid = db_id()
            and d.status != 256
         group by d.dbid
     end
     ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASE Job Scheduler](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20001.1570/html/jsusers/title.htm) would be a more stable method of running your purge, instead of *waitfor*.

The reason *dump transaction with truncate_only* is not recommended for production systems is it's impact on recoverability. You can work around this issue by dumping the transaction logs to file as part of your process.  That way you can deal with both the log filling issue, as well as maintaining the ability to recover your system in case of database failure.

More information on dumping the transaction log can be found in the [Sybase ASE 15.7 Reference Manual: Commands](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/X47924.htm)

Also, sp_thresholdaction can be setup to automatically dump the transaction log when it reaches a certain threshold.  The [Sybase ASE 15.7 Reference Manual: Procedures](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1570/html/sprocs/X67172.htm) has that example.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Michael. My DBA has just confirmed that our databases are configured with "truncate log on chkpt" and "abort tran on log full". In this case, I can safely use "dump transaction with truncate only". Is that right?

Comment: Hey Michael,
I asked my DBA to setup job scheduler in our ASE but he says there is only one of our DBAs know about job schedulers and sybase ASE job schedulers are a pain to use. He asked me to avoid it and go for cron. Could you please let me know your thoughts on ASE job schedulers and let me know if it is really pain enough to avoid? Appreciate any recommendations on this.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Just one last thing to confirm on this. So, the ASE job scheduler can be used programmatically within my procedure. Is this right? I am planning to create a scheduled job by invoking "sp_sjobcreate" within my stored procedure. Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

1. waitfor should't harm your performance, but you may lost this session in case of ASE restart, DBA kill, connection lost with client side etc., to me, it looks like as unstable solution. consider to use cron or ASE Job Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Use Job Scheduler with caution - look out for known bugs in this ASE java function e.g. the need to recycle ASE just to bring a failed JS task from its slumber makes the use of JS at higher risks than, say, waitfor.

Cron is more reliable.